# How to do app routing with the newest Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

the title may not be clear.. but.. before, I can do this:

```
/* file 1*/
app = express.createServer();

/* main file*/
server = express.createServer();

// route
server.get('/whatever', function(req, res) { res.send('whatever'); });
server.use('/test/*', app);
```

But for the newest Express.js, I can't.  any idea?

Comment: For what it's worth, many people have had trouble with Express 3. Try 2.5.9 and see if it's better.

Comment: to use `server.get` you shoud `server.use(server.router)` then start adding routes. And `/test/*` should only be `/test`, I think. what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed in version 3.x. The basic example on the express web site shows the following code now:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: Well.. i know the basic.    I'm converting a complex system from express 2 to 3.   One problem is... in 2, I can have multiple apps (or child apps) add to the root app by this:  app.use('/api1', app1); app.use('/api2', app2);   so anything with path /api1 will actually use app1.

Comment: I see. I don't know about multiple/child apps, though.

Comment: np. thanks though.  I work around this by passing the 'main server' to the child app. I don't create new app in the child but appending .get , .post..etc to the main server instead.  I think that's a much cleaner way.